# Choose which set of methods an object has, based on argument during object creation - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, interface, new-operator

I have searched and read for a few hours yet I still cant understand the basic design pattern for creating a new object that has a choice of different methods (of the same name) that is set dependant on one of the arguments. here's some code to explain what I am trying to do.
All advice and alternative approaches welcome. I hope someone can emancipate me form this cloud of ignorance.
Thanks

```
function BaseConstructor(whichMethods) {
    if (whichMethods==='a') {
         // do something to incorporate methodSetA
    }
    else if (whichMethods==='b') {
        // do something to incorporate methodSetB
    }

    this.init();
};

var methodSetA = {
    init: function() {
        // do initialisation A way
    },
    speak: function() {
        alert('i speak AAA way')
    }
};

var methodSetB = {
    init: function() {
        // do initialisation B way
    },
    speak: function(){
        alert('i got BBB all the way')
    }
};

thing = new BaseConstructor('b'); 
// b is an instance of BaseConstructor and has done the bWay init() function

thing.speak() // return alert 'i got BBB all the way'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using a factory function (a regular function that creates the appropriate object for you):

```
function BaseConstructor(whichMethods) {
    var elem;
    if (whichMethods==='a') {
         elem = new MethodSetA();
    } else if (whichMethods==='b') {
         elem = new MethodSetB();
    } else {
         // figure out what to do here if whichMethods is neither of the previous options
    }

    elem.init();
    return(elem);
};
```

And invoke it as a regular function call:

```
var thing = BaseConstructor('b');
thing.speak();
```

Note: there is no use of `new` with `BaseConstructor()` as it's a regular function call.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for the prompt reply! Factory design pattern -- I must have read about that 5 times today, and kinda thought that is what I need, but always got so distracted in extraneous details. Thanks again @jfriend00

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do it your way using "method sets," you can iterate and copy into `this` ([here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/2WGyq/)):

```
function copy(source, destination) {
    for(var x in source) {
        if(source.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            destination[x] = source[x];
        }
    }
}

function BaseConstructor(whichMethods) {
    if(whichMethods === 'a') {
        copy(methodSetA, this);
    } else if(whichMethods === 'b') {
        copy(methodSetB, this);
    }

    this.init();
}
```

Personally, though, I'd prefer to assign directly to `this`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and finding a way to do it 'my way', I will learn from your code. Thanks again@minitech

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for factory pattern.
Example:

```
    function objectFactory(whichMethods) {
        if (whichMethods==='a') {
            return new objectSetA();
        }
        else if (whichMethods==='b') {
            return new objectSetB()
        }
    };
    function objectSetA() {
        this.init = function() {
        // do initialisation A way
        },
        this.speak = function() {
            alert('i speak AAA way')
        }
    };

    function objectSetB() {
        this.init = function() {
        // do initialisation B way
        },
        this.speak = function(){
            alert('i got BBB all the way')
        }
    };
    var thing = objectFactory('b'); 
    thing.speak();
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and clear reply, indeed I do need a factory ! @petar

Comment: The speak methods should be on the respective contructor's prototype.

Comment: @RobG that makes sense to put speak() method on the prototype. Is there any reason why you don't suggest the init() method also on the prototype ?

Comment: init() and speak() methods are best suited in the prototype yes. In fact I put all variables in the function constructor and all methods in the prototype.